# asp.net core modelstate validation custom error message. how to to put quotations or some other characters in place of input value

Tags: asp.net-core

I am getting following response from my asp.net core 3.1 api after i put custom model validation in startup

```
{
"success": "failed",
"message": "fk entity id: The value '<script>alert(1);</script>' is not valid for fk_entity_id."
}
```

My code in startup is like

```
private void CustomValidationResponse(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(
                options => options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = actionContext =>
                {
                    return CustomErrorResponse(actionContext);
                }
                );
        }

private BadRequestObjectResult CustomErrorResponse(ActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var errorRecordList = actionContext.ModelState
              .Where(modelError => modelError.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
              .Select(modelError => new
              {
                  ErrorField = modelError.Key,
                  ErrorDescription = modelError.Value.Errors.FirstOrDefault().ErrorMessage
              }).ToList();

            string concatenatedMessage = string.Empty;
            foreach (var error in errorRecordList)
            {
                concatenatedMessage += error.ErrorField.Replace("_", " ") + ": " + error.ErrorDescription + ",";
            }
            concatenatedMessage = concatenatedMessage.TrimEndExt(",");
            return new BadRequestObjectResult(new
            {
                success = "failed",
                message = concatenatedMessage
            });
        }
```

What i want is somehow putting some quotation/escape cahracter in place of value in my message response something like

{
"success": "failed",
"message": "fk entity id: The value ['alert(1);'] is not valid for fk_entity_id."
}

Comment: Any help guys in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was to avoid xss attack
For the timebeing i have used following solution

```
private BadRequestObjectResult CustomErrorResponse(ActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var errorRecordList = actionContext.ModelState
              .Where(modelError => modelError.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
              .Select(modelError => new
              {
                  ErrorField = modelError.Key,
                  ErrorDescription = modelError.Value.Errors.FirstOrDefault().ErrorMessage.Replace("<script>", "'[<script>]'").Replace("</script>", "'[</script>]'")
              }).ToList();

            string concatenatedMessage = string.Empty;
            foreach (var error in errorRecordList)
            {
                concatenatedMessage += error.ErrorField.Replace("_", " ") + ": " + error.ErrorDescription + ",";
            }
            concatenatedMessage = concatenatedMessage.TrimEndExt(",");
            //if(co)
            return new BadRequestObjectResult(new
            {
                success = "failed",
                message = concatenatedMessage

                //,  errors = errorRecordList
            });
        }
```